# beginner asynchronus JS - do i ever have to use "then" every time i want the value

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm using PouchDB which is async and i'm new to async..

So if i get a Doc from pouchdb i have to use `.then` to see the actual result. Thats clear for me, but do i have to call `.then` every single time i want this value?

For example i made a SettingsService where i can store my settings key / value style.

```
// Get Setting
settingsService.get = function(key) {
    return settingDB.get(key).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

When i wanna get the setting do i have to make every time this big `.then` block?

```
// Get Time of Last Sync
settingsService.get('lastSync').then(function (setting) {
    $scope.lastSync = setting.value;   // now it's assigned isn't it?
    console.log(setting);
});

//edit, but this is still is undefined.. so again use then?
console.log($scope.lastSync);
```

Now what if i want the same setting again little bit later in the code, do i everytime to repeat this `.then` stuff?

Comment: If you have already assigned it to `$scope.lastSync`, then you can just access `$scope.lastSync`. But if you want to get a value from a promise multiple times, then you will generally need to use the "same big `.then` stuff each time.

Comment: Yes, if you need an updated value from the service.  Otherwise just read from the scope variable you populated the first time you called the service.

Comment: @JLRishe so i assigend it, but if i acces it now, it's still undefined. I edited the last codeblock, so you see what i mean..

Comment: @user2834172 Yes, you obviously can't access it immediately after you call `.get()`, because the value will not be there yet. If you access it _after_ it has been assigned to the scope, then you will be fine.

Comment: @user2834172 I've added my view on that, you can check my answer

Comment: @JLRishe ok thanks, i think it's clear now, even i think this stuff is little bit stupid and i could not believe there is no easier way..

Comment: @user2834172 Don't call it stupid just because you don't understand it yet. That's no kind of attitude to have. For your perusal: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/async%20%26%20performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would require `then` if you're trying to access the value anywhere outside of current `then` block.

```
// Get Time of Last Sync
settingsService.get('lastSync').then(function (setting) {
    $scope.lastSync = setting.value;
    console.log(setting);

   // inside the then function, you can access the $scope.lastSync variable directly

});
```

Anything you want to do with respect to `$scope.lastSync` must be inside this function. Else you can even use `$scope.$watch(lastSync, function(newValue){})` to process something outside the `then` function. This will make sure that it will run after the value has changed and it's again similar to `then`.

But outside the `then`, you must use `then` because you won't know when the value will resolve.

So `console.log($scope.lastSync);` anywhere outside the `then` will give you undefined. You can use `$timeout` to do console.log but you can't guarantee when the value will be available. It's totally depended on the service call.

Though you've assigned it inside the then, `then` would execute at some point of time when the service call succeeds. But you're printing the console.log for `$scope.lastSync` immediately. So it will be still be `undefined` because the `then` callback has not executed yet.

Comment: ok thats what i thought, but i cant believe it =). what if i have a big customer controller, it's likely, that i have to access the customer so many times..do i write 30 times `.then` or wrap everything in the controller in one `.then`?

Comment: Yes, you would wrap everything inside one then. Still you can organise code using multiple functions and call those functions inside the `then`

Comment: That was my final question i think. Thank you very very much! Now i know how to organize my code clean =)